# Different names for XAMPP virtual hosts

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I've set up XAMPP (on Windows 7) to use virtual hosts in a simple manner. `localhost:80` points to Apache's `htdocs` folder, and `localhost:81` points to `D:\Projects\`. This works like a charm.

However, I would like to be able to access my projects folder using not only `http://localhost:81/`, but also using `http://projects/`. Windows' `hosts` file doesn't care about ports - how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems relevant to [setting up multiple virtual hosts on XAMPP for windows 7](http://ailoo.net/2008/07/set-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-for-windows/).

I'm not sure using ports is the best approach. You might be better off setting up entirely different domain names to redirect to the correct local directory.